# Finding model created using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, arctoolbox

I made a model in the ModelBuilder (arcgis 10.2) and saved it. Unfortunately, not some place where I can find it again.

However, if I want to save a new model (save as..),the old model is there in toolbox.tbx.

Does anyone know how I can re-open my model again? ArcCatalog is not helping me so far.

Comment: do an operating system search on *.tbx - what OS are you using?

Comment: You could try using the Search window of ArcMap to look for it by name.  Whether you find it will depend on what locations have been indexed.  However, I think the Windows Explorer search on *.tbx may be wiser if Search does not find it immediately.

Comment: Thx! I found the .tbx file by windows explorer search. ArcCatalog still didn't see it. I copied the .tbx file in into anoter map. Then, ArcCatalog saw the files in it and I could reopen in.

Answer (score 1):

Try refreshing the toolbox.  The F5 key will refresh it, or you can right-click on it and select 'refresh.'  That should update the contents of the toolbox to show your model saved under its new name.

Answer (score 1):

Open Catalog, expand "Home -  Documents\ArcGIS", then expand "Toolbox.tbx", models you made will be listed there. Right-click the model (tool) you made and choose "Edit", do not choose "Open",  now your model will be in ModelBuilder that you can make changes and save.